# How to merge arrays creating an array with subarrays?

Tags: php, merge, arrays

I have following arrays:

Min values:

```
[2006] => 117
[2007] => 117
[2008] => 117
[2009] => 117
[2010] => 117
[2011] => 117
[2012] => 118
[2013] => 132
```

Average:

```
[2006] => 170
[2007] => 174
...
[2013] => 166
```

Max values:

```
[2006] => 291
[2007] => 630
...
[2013] => 246
```

How can I merge them so I have following array with subarray:

```
[2006] => array (117, 170, 291),
[2007] => array (117, 174, 630),
...
[2013] => array (132, 166, 246)
```

A solution without subarrays would be apreciate as well. Something like that would solve the problem too:

```
[2006] => [117, 170, 291]
[2007] => [117, 174, 630]
...
[2013] => [132, 166, 246]
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: foreach loop, use the keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

made assumption about array names:

```
$new=array();

foreach($min as $k=>$v){
$new[$k]=array($v,$average[$k],$max[$k]);
}
```

did not really understand what "solution without subarrays" meant - did you want a string or?

**EDIT** string creation

```
$new='';

foreach($min as $k=>$v){
$new.='['.$v.','.$average[$k].','.$max[$k].'],';
}

$new=rtrim($new,',');//remove last comma
```

Comment: yeah, a had a string in mind, because in the end what I really need is a string just like [401,170,118],[356,181,120],... This goes to google charts :-D Do you have any idea?

Comment: Many thanks @Dagon! Both solutions are working just fine! My bad here ;-)

Comment: Hey @Dagon we forgot to include the $key in the string. The chart will only work if we insert the year as well. Sorry that I didn't mentioned it before. We'll need something like [2012,401,170,118],[2013, 356,181,120]. Could you please still help me?

Comment: I tried:
    foreach($resultMax as $k=>$v){
        $new.='['.$v[$k].','.$v.','.$result06[$k].','.$resultMin[$k].'],';
    }
but then received a  Uninitialized string offset: error.

Comment: it would be `$new.='['.$k.','.$v.','.$average[$k].','.$max[$k].'],';`

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple, just write a foreach loop, to loop over one of the arrays, I used the $mins array here.

Then grab the equivalent data from each of the other arrays and add them all into your new array using the key as the key to the new array.

```
$mins = array(2006 => 117, 2007 => 117, 2008 => 117,
              2009 => 117, 2010 => 117, 2011 => 117,
              2012 => 118, 2013 => 132);

$avgs = array(2006 => 170, 2007 => 174, 2008 => 169,
              2009 => 179, 2010 => 180, 2011 => 181,
              2012 => 182, 2013 => 183);

$maxs = array(2006 => 217, 2007 => 233, 2008 => 322,
              2009 => 215, 2010 => 216, 2011 => 217,
              2012 => 231, 2013 => 232);

$newArray = array();

foreach( $mins as $year => $min ) {
    $newArray[$year] = array( $min, $avgs[$year], $maxs[$year] );
}

print_r( $newArray );
```

Output is :-

```
Array
(
    [2006] => Array
        (
            [0] => 117
            [1] => 170
            [2] => 217
        )

    [2007] => Array
        (
            [0] => 117
            [1] => 174
            [2] => 233
        )

    [2008] => Array
        (
            [0] => 117
            [1] => 169
            [2] => 322
        )

    [2009] => Array
        (
            [0] => 117
            [1] => 179
            [2] => 215
        )

    [2010] => Array
        (
            [0] => 117
            [1] => 180
            [2] => 216
        )

    [2011] => Array
        (
            [0] => 117
            [1] => 181
            [2] => 217
        )

    [2012] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118
            [1] => 182
            [2] => 231
        )

    [2013] => Array
        (
            [0] => 132
            [1] => 183
            [2] => 232
        )

)
```

And using the new array syntax it would be

```
$mins = [2006 => 117, 2007 => 117, 2008 => 117,
              2009 => 117, 2010 => 117, 2011 => 117,
              2012 => 118, 2013 => 132];

$avgs = [2006 => 170, 2007 => 174, 2008 => 169,
              2009 => 179, 2010 => 180, 2011 => 181,
              2012 => 182, 2013 => 183];

$maxs = [2006 => 217, 2007 => 233, 2008 => 322,
              2009 => 215, 2010 => 216, 2011 => 217,
              2012 => 231, 2013 => 232];

$newArray = [];

foreach( $mins as $year => $min ) {
    $newArray[$year] = [ $min, $avgs[$year], $maxs[$year] ];
}

print_r( $newArray );
```

And if you want the result as an array of string just change it like this

```
foreach( $mins as $year => $min ) {
    $newArray[$year] = sprintf('[%d,%d,%d]', $min, $avgs[$year], $maxs[$year]);
}

print_r( $newArray );
```

Giving this result

```
Array
(
    [2006] => [117,170,217]
    [2007] => [117,174,233]
    [2008] => [117,169,322]
    [2009] => [117,179,215]
    [2010] => [117,180,216]
    [2011] => [117,181,217]
    [2012] => [118,182,231]
    [2013] => [132,183,232]
)
```